# S3 coping files between buckets on different accounts without modifying any polices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

S3 coping files between buckets on different accounts without modifying any polices.
S3 coping files between buckets on different accounts without modifying any polices.
S3 coping files between buckets on different accounts without modifying any polices

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information. For example, what are you trying to do? What have you tried? What problems are you experiencing? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way without editing any policies is to use something(IAM Role, User, Instance with IAM Role...) that has access to both S3 Bucket in both accounts and move it over that. Probably a Bash script or a Lambda function with Access could also help.

If you don't have a resource with access to both then there is no way to move the Files without editing policies.

If you mean without editing S3 Policies then you can add IAM Roles to both accounts with access to the Bucket and assign them to move the files. Either with your Account or a resource that can run scripts.